# Selenium Webdriver for JavaScript - Add 'Sizzle' strategy

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I did some poking around in the selenium-webdriver source code, and found a list of element locator strategies:

```
webdriver.Locator.Strategy = {
  'className': webdriver.Locator.factory_('class name'),
  'class name': webdriver.Locator.factory_('class name'),
  'css': webdriver.Locator.factory_('css selector'),
  'id': webdriver.Locator.factory_('id'),
  'js': webdriver.Locator.factory_('js'),
  'linkText': webdriver.Locator.factory_('link text'),
  'link text': webdriver.Locator.factory_('link text'),
  'name': webdriver.Locator.factory_('name'),
  'partialLinkText': webdriver.Locator.factory_('partial link text'),
  'partial link text': webdriver.Locator.factory_('partial link text'),
  'tagName': webdriver.Locator.factory_('tag name'),
  'tag name': webdriver.Locator.factory_('tag name'),
  'xpath': webdriver.Locator.factory_('xpath')
};
```

Would it be possible to extend this with the [sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) selector engine?

Someone [did it in Java](http://selenium.polteq.com/en/injecting-the-sizzle-css-selector-library/) but I can't figure out how to get it to work with the JavaScript library.

---

When I try

```
webdriver.Locator.Strategy.sizzle = webdriver.Locator.factory_('sizzle');
```

I get :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'Strategy' of undefined

So it's not trivial to extend...

Comment: Why do you need to use Sizzle?

Answer (score 1):

From my own perspective, the css2/css3 selector could cover your need.

Because of the bad default api, you would use a un-friendly api like this `driver.findElement(webdriver.By.css('input[name="textbox"]'))`. It's indeed bad without a comprehensive document.

I suggest you use https://npmjs.org/package/webdriver-helper to get the friendly api support.

`browser.element('input[name="textbox"]')` and `browser.link(':contains("partial link text")')` could help you.